# Groupby and compare columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

What is the simplest way to compare two columns using groupby - without apply/lambda?

```
df  product1 product2  person
0    apple   apples     abby
1    apple   apple      abby
...
```

```
df.groupby("person").product1.eq(df.groupby("person").product2)
```

Expected Output

```
0  False
1  True
```

Comment: What is the grouping used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit tricky to solve without `apply` but you can use `merge` to compare ('person', 'product2) to ('person', 'product1'):

```
idx = (df.rename(columns={'product2': 'product'})[['person', 'product']].reset_index()
         .merge(df.rename(columns={'product1': 'product'})[['person', 'product']], 
                on=['person', 'product'])['index'].unique())

df['compare'] = df.index.isin(idx)
print(df)

# Output
  product1 product2 person  compare
0    apple   apples   abby    False
1    apple    apple   abby     True
```